# SwiftUI view sometimes creates Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6002005b8368), when I put array as a parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-catalina, xcode11.3

SwiftUI View file

```
struct NoteListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var presenter: NoteListPresenter
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            AddNoteButton()
            Text(presenter.noteViewModels[0].title)
        }
    }
}

struct NoteListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NoteListView()
    }
}
```

I first got this error when I finished writing the logic and started to writing Views. After add my custom button **AddNoteButton()** to main view, it gave the following error, although it worked before I added this button. I tried to rewrite my views, but although it works at the beginning at some random point of time it throws this error again(by other words sometimes it works, but when i add some irrelevant code it stops working and discarding changes doesn't solve the problem). It always highlights line, where I use noteViewModels array inside of the NoteListView.

Also I added method which prints array to presenter and it always prints everything.

```
func printAll(){
    for element in self.noteViewModels{
        print(element.title)
    }
}
```

I can not add other files to question, because there is too many of them. But i hope that I gave enough information, If you think that there is not enough information you are free to ask me or you can check out github: 
https://github.com/ShynggysSaparbek/ViperNotesWithRealm/

Xcode version 11.3
Mac OS version Catalina 10.15.2

Comment: What is the code for `AddNotButton`? What happens if you comment it out? Or comment out parts of it?

Comment: Add button is a view.  It is actually a navigation view, which shows another views.

Comment: I meant to say that the problem code is probably in `AddNoteButton`. To solve it, you can try commenting out parts until it works, and this way find the problematic code. If you're not able to solve it, you can post the code here so others may be able to help.

Comment: Code is to big write it here, so i add link to github

Comment: The `AddNoteButton` class seems fine, so maybe `noteViewModels[0]` doesn't exist. I.e., `noteViewModels` is empty. Try commenting the line with `Text` and see if the crash goes away.

Comment: As I wrote in the post, noteViewModels is not empty, because func printAll() works and prints all the members of array. So noteViewModels only doesn't work as a parameter of ForEach SwiftUI structure. Probably that's a bag of SwiftUI, because previous versions had similar problem with ForEach. So it is not possible to solve it, so I will just rewrite code in with storyboards. Anyway; thanks for help and sorry for grammar mistakes.

Comment: What happens if you comment the line with `AddNoteButton()`? What happens if you comment the line with the `Text()`? Try that, and you may be able to pinpoint the source of the problem.

Comment: I tried it, and mistakes goes away if comment Text(), but doesn't disappear if comment AddNoteButton.  I think, that it is because my array can not be inside of SwiftUI structure for some reason.

Comment: Which one? Both? Next step is to comment out the `@EnvironmentObject` as well. Maybe it's not passed from the containing views?

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, I created custom data and saved it in presenter and removed property wrapper, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Just to make sure, try the following code for your view: `struct NoteListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("test")
        }
    }
}`

Comment: It doesn't create error

Comment: So now add just one of the  deleted lines: `@EnvironmentObject var presenter: NoteListPresenter` . What happens?